# Can $f$ satisfy $f(p,q) > (p+q)$ at some point $(p,q) \in \mathbb{R^2_+}$?

Tags: calculus, functions, functional-equations

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R^2_+} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $f(1,1) = 1$, $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2_+}$ and $f$ is homogenous of degree $1$. Does there exist any such $f$ that also satisfies $f(p,q) > (p+q)$ for some point $(p,q) \in \mathbb{R^2_+}$?

Please read the comments if you're looking for context. I am not very familiar with the rules of this site.

Comment: Does homogeneous of degree 1 means $f(x,y)=ax+ay+b$?

Comment: @Andrei no, it means $f(tx,ty) = tf(x,y)$ for every $t > 0$.

Comment: Do you mean $f: \mathbb{R}_+^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ rather than $\to \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @aschepler yes, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: what are your thoughts? What have you tried?  We generally frown upon "solve this problem without any context/work/attempts" here

Comment: @Alan I didn't copy the question from anywhere, which is why there's no content/work/attempts. My instructor said that for all $z = f(x,y)$, $z = f(z,z) < 2z$ tells that $z - (x+y)$ can never be positive. So I was mainly looking for a counter-example because the reasoning didn't convince me.

Comment: @Isa: If $f$ is differentiable with respect to $x$ and/or $y$, can you draw any conclusions?

Comment: @Isa: you should copy the comment about context in the question. Comments are meant to be deleted eventually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also view this type of function using polar coordinates.

$$ f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) = r g(\theta) $$

The homogeneity requirement is satisfied by the fact that $\frac{f}{r}$ does not depend on $r$. The requirement $f(1,1)=1$ forces that $g\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Otherwise, $g$ can be any function on the interval $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. If $g$ is continuous, so is $f$. If $g$ is differentiable and your definition of $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ does not include $0$, then $f$ is also differentiable. And if at any value $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have $g(\theta) > \cos \theta + \sin \theta$, this means that $f(x,y) < x+y$ using the usual relations $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$.

If $(0,0)$ is in the domain, I think the only possible *differentiable* $f$ are plane equations $f(x,y) = ax+by$. This can still lead to values where $f(x,y) > x+y$. For example, $f(x,y) = 3x-2y$ gives $f(1,1)=1$ and $f(3,1)=7 > 3+1$.

Comment: I was about to ask if we can find a counter-example for differentiable $f$. I had one in mind, but it was in the form of a visualization rather than a mathematical construction. Thank you. I'm sorry the site isn't allowing me to upvote you, but your construction was very helpful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't require that the function be continuous, I think the answer is yes. For example, define $f(x, y)$ to be $2x$ on the line $y = \frac{x}{2}$, $x$ on the line $y = x$, $2y$ on the line $y = 2x$, and 0 everywhere else. Then for example at $(1, \frac{1}{2})$, $f(x, y) = 2$ while $x + y = \frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. Can we say construct a counter-example for the case when $f$ is continuous (or even differentiable)?

Comment: my visual intuition says yes in the case where you add the requirement that $f$ is continuous. Take the function above and find the plane in 3-space spanned by vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$, where $v_1$ spans the line $y = \frac{x}{2}$ and $v_2$ spans the line $y = x$. For all points $(x, y)$ that lie between the lines $y = \frac{x}{2}$ and $y = x$, define $f(x, y)$ to be the $z$ coordinate of the plane. Perform a similar procedure 3 more times...

Comment: ...once using vectors spanning the lines $y = x$ and $y = 2x$, once using vectors spanning the lines $y = 0$ and $y = \frac{x}{2}$, and once using vectors spanning the lines $x = 0$ and $y = 2x$.

Comment: yes, that works for continuity but not for differentiability, right?

Comment: of course, once you have the equations of the relevant planes, you can define this piecewise function explicitly